# suffix template <T_>

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this two sourse code one is mine and other get from internet just I want to ask what is the deferent of using template between the two code what is node is deferent than mine
my node code

```
template <typename Object>
    struct Node
    {
        Object  data;
        Node   *prev;
        Node   *next;

        Node( const Object & d = Object(), Node * p = nullptr, Node * n = nullptr )
            : data(d), prev(p), next(n){}

        Node( Object && d, Node * p = nullptr, Node * n = nullptr )
            : data( std::move( d )), prev( p), next(n ) { }
    };
```

other code

```
template<typename T_>
struct node
{
        T_ data;
        node<T_>* prev;
        node<T_>* next;
        node<T_>(T_ t, node<T_>* p, node<T_>* n) : data(t), prev(p), next(n) {}
        node( node && n ) {        // Rvalue move ctor
                data = std::move(n.data);
                prev = std::move(n.prev);
                next = std::move(n.next);
        }
        node& operator = ( node && n ) { // Rvalue = operator
                data = std::move(n.data);
                prev = std::move(n.prev);
                next = std::move(n.next);
                return *this;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The second piece is poor:

1. No need to specify the template parameters when referring to the instantiation within the class template. I.e. inside `node<T_>`, `node_` refers to `node_<T_>`.
2. Move constructor and move assignment do not do anything useful and should probably be removed in favour of compiler generated ones.

It is easy to make things bigger, it is hard to make them any better.

Comment: you mean from my code?

Comment: @user3277743 Not sure I understand your question.